# Wired Connection on 20.04 Slower than Both WiFi on 20.04 or Wired Using Win10

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

**Background:** My connection is 1000 mb/s down and 40 mb/s up. I regularly get speed test results very close to that from my wired devices.

I recently purchased an inexpensive mini pc to mess around with, and it came with Win10 installed. I unboxed it, connected it via ethernet to my EdgeSwitch (which itself is connected to my EdgeRouter), booted into Windows, and performed some speed tests, with results ranging from 900+ down/40 up using `speedtest.net` to as high as 1599 down/43 up using the Comcast business speed test.

I then made a bootable USB stick with 20.04 on it, rebooted onto the USB device, and installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu Desktop on the machine. Now, still using the same wired connection, **I can only get 30 down/40 up**. If I disable the ethernet connection and connect via WiFi, I get 200-300 down/40 up. If I plug either of my laptops into the same exact cable the Ubuntu box is using, I get my 900+ mb/s downloads again.

Things I have tried so far (after all the furious googling I can think of):

- The machine has the Realtek RTL8111/RTL8168 NIC. I removed the r8169 driver that can supposedly cause issues and installed the r8168 driver. No difference.
- Used ethtool to verify the interface was set to full duplex (it is). Tried turning off autonegotiate and manually setting it to full duplex. No difference.
- Checked ip route for anything that looked out of place. Default route is correct.
- Disabled IPv6.
- Checked for any relevant BIOS settings. Tried disabling wake on LAN. No other NIC related settings are present in the BIOS. No difference.

If anyone can think of anything else to check/try, that would be much appreciated. I have exhausted my knowledge at this point. Thanks in advance.

Per request, the results of `sudo lshw -C network` (enp1s0 is the interface in question):

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 5c:85:7e:40:89:c2
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:127 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:a1304000-a1304fff memory:a1300000-a1303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 5c:85:7e:40:89:c3
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:129 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 91
       serial: 24:41:8c:15:f9:6e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 memory:a1100000-a1101fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: veth6ffe1c4
       serial: 6a:02:41:90:a4:6a
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: br-4a0d5cc98154
       serial: 02:42:6d:97:46:a3
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.251.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: veth6b2e330
       serial: 0a:cd:f8:bc:97:4d
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: br-8248484a3e46
       serial: 02:42:31:06:62:49
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.251.129 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:4
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: vethab446ab
       serial: 12:2c:81:08:fa:68
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:5
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 6
       logical name: vetha7734c2
       serial: 2a:83:79:5a:c8:e7
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:6
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: veth67b3a82
       serial: 56:9d:e3:98:b5:01
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:7
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 8
       logical name: veth7ac8a55
       serial: 66:c0:27:fc:19:56
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:8
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       logical name: vethcefd008
       serial: 5e:42:a4:e0:08:43
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:9
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: a
       logical name: veth99ea1fc
       serial: 2e:86:07:86:64:e9
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:10
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: b
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:04:ba:ff:72
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:11
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: c
       logical name: vethd3648ee
       serial: 32:06:af:d8:c7:92
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:12
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: d
       logical name: veth6ae5338
       serial: 76:91:8e:00:9a:0b
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:13
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: e
       logical name: vethbc28f40
       serial: 8a:ce:b8:73:02:86
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:14
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: f
       logical name: veth6278cb8
       serial: de:dd:8b:d6:eb:af
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:15
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 10
       logical name: veth1494606
       serial: ca:4c:79:f9:03:2f
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Does the EdgeSwitch have gigabit LAN ports? What happens if you connect directly to the EdgeRouter? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Edited as requested. Everything is gigabit LAN ports, and every wired device I have but this one gets full D/L speeds plugged into either the router or switch. In fact, the device in question got full D/L speeds when it was running Win10. Since I put Ubuntu on it, it has severely throttled D/L speeds regardless of where I plug it in. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Do me a favor. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and retry speedtest. Report back.

Comment: Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables?

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: @heynnema Booted to USB. Speedtest even worse (17 mb/s down). Using Cat 6 cables, but as I mentioned, everything works fine with other devices or this device with Windows installed instead of Ubuntu. Output of that command is GB7BV03. It is a Minisforum GK41. Thanks again!

Comment: I couldn't find a BIOS update/listing for that computer. Maybe you can look yourself?

Comment: @heynnema From what I can tell, I don't think any updated BIOS exists. It's a cheap off brand mini PC. I am pretty close to just giving up on it as it was just supposed to be something to mess with before this issue piqued my intellectual curiosity. Thanks for your efforts.